# draw a rectangle inside an reactangle with adjustable size in python

Tags: python, drawing

which python library is the best one for drawing such elements

[image]

it is important that the rectangle inside a rectangle is centered and has an adjustable size and can be colored.

and also the possibility of drawing several in a row and a column is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best bet is starting with Turtle, give this a read:
[https://realpython.com/beginners-guide-python-turtle/#:~:text=turtle%20is%20a%20pre%2Dinstalled,gives%20the%20library%20its%20name](https://realpython.com/beginners-guide-python-turtle/#:%7E:text=turtle%20is%20a%20pre%2Dinstalled,gives%20the%20library%20its%20name).

Comment: In the end I took mathplotlib :) but anyway your suggestion would also work :)